# How do I run cmder inside atom on windows 10?

Tags: cmder

I have install **cmder** and **atom editor (v. 1.19.3)**. Also install the *platformio-ide-package* for atom. And I do еverything that has been described in this article - http://thebar.cc/atom-editor-cmder/, but in my atom editor ->settings missing the part with **Shell Override: ...** , where I can change the path. Is this is a bug on my editor? And can anyone tell me how to fix that and set the Atom editor with the Cmder console.

Comment: nobody knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Got it working with simply putting `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` into **Shell Override** and `C:\path\to\cmder\vendor\init.bat` into **Auto Run Command**, no quotes, no nothing.

Comment: also ... I've appended `&& clear` to the Auto Run Command, just looks cleaner, imho :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not much of answer(I can't comment yet), but it might help.

***Shell override*** is in: Atom Settings(or *ctrl +* ,) > Packages > platformio-ide-terminal > Settings. Scroll down and you will see.[image: Shell Override]

I didn't make it work yet(actually by googling found this question). If I do I'll edit this comment(Hope I can do it). I'm on Windows 7.

**EDIT:**

It works(win7). What I did is I removed double quotes (**"**) around the path inside the file **atom.bat**. Of cause edit path to where is your cmder folder is.

Comment: Thanks! I find this field and do what do you suggested, but still can't run the cmder console in atom. In the console says: **"The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."**       But I check my path to the cmder and is right.

Comment: @Santiya I just ran into this problem as well, and the issue is that the website uses “ and ” (the unicode left and right double quotation marks) instead of " (regular quotation mark). Simply delete all the quotation marks in your atom.bat file and re-type them.

Answer (score 1):

Use [platformio-ide-terminal](https://atom.io/packages/platformio-ide-terminal) and in the settings of the package:

- **Shell Override** `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`
- **Shell Arguments** `/K C:\path\to\cmder\vendor\init.bat`

Answer (score 1):

Since my machine is slow to start the batch script, here's an elegant way to add a loading message so it doesn't seem like the terminal is unresponsive, just add this to AutoRun:

```
@cls & echo Loading... & C:\your\path\cmder\vendor\init.bat
```